# Get request not logging anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/", function(onWebsite) {
     console.log($(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0].attr("href"));
});
```

Whenever I run it, it does not log anything to the console, all it says is: "Object {readyState: 1}". However, if I remove the .attr("href"), it works. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: does find return an object or a list of objects?

Comment: An object, because I set the node to [0].

Comment: `[0]` returns a DOM node which doesn't have any `attr()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery function you need to use it with jQuery object.

Use

```
$(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate').attr("href")
```

As per your current code `$(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0]` will return you underlying DOM element which doesn't have `.attr()` method.

You can use `href` property or [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method

```
$(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0].href
```

*OR*

```
$(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0].getAttribute('href')
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the next item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/", function(onWebsite) {
     console.log(onWebsite.find('.name.notranslate')[0].attr("href"));
});
```

onWebsite must not be wrapped with the jQuery selector as its a return from a function.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this approach:

```
var a;
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/", function(onWebsite) {
     a = $(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0];
     console.log(a);
});
```

You will get

```
<a class="name notranslate" href="/Headless-Horseman-item?id=134082613" title="Headless Horseman">Headless Horseman</a>
```

So var a is the HTML Tag with href attribute. **HTML tags doesn't have jQuery methods - only jQuery objects selected from DOM or "wrapped/selected HTML"**

Here you can:

1. reference `.href` to get href
2. wrap `a` in jQuery to get: `$(a).attr('href')`

So end code would be (variant 1 is better):

```
var a;
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/", function(onWebsite) {
         a = $(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0].href
         console.log(a);
    });
```

or without creation of temp variable

```
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/", function(onWebsite) {
     console.log($(onWebsite).find('.name.notranslate')[0].href);
});
```